# IAR iccarm Cmake

Tags: cmake, iar, cortex-m

I have some trouble doing a migration from IAR IDE to Cmake/IAR compiler for arm:

According to my understanding, with a correct CMakeList.txt, I try:

```
/c/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -G"MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="C:\CMake\bin\Modules\Compiler\iar.cmake" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 7.0/arm/bin/iccarm.exe" -DCMAKE_ASM_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 7.0/arm/bin/iasmarm.exe" ..
```

I get:

```
-- The C compiler identification is IAR
-- The ASM compiler identification is IAR
-- Found assembler: C:/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 7.0/arm/bin/iasmarm.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 7.0/arm/bin/iccarm.exe
CMake Error at C:/CMake/bin/Modules/Compiler/IAR.cmake:41 (message):
  The IAR compiler for this architecture is not yet supported by CMake.
  Please go to https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues and enter a
  feature request there.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Projects/LabPadIntegration/lpd_firmware/LABPAD_IAR/FIRMWARE/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  C:/Projects/LabPadIntegration/lpd_firmware/LABPAD_IAR/FIRMWARE/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Projects/LabPadIntegration/lpd_firmware/LABPAD_IAR/FIRMWARE/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Projects/LabPadIntegration/lpd_firmware/LABPAD_IAR/FIRMWARE/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

This sounds strange because if I read the IAR.cmake, the case where this fatal error rises is when the compiler does not match "arm" neither avr. 
So I put a message output with the CMAKE_C_COMPILER argument and I get:

```
-- CMAKE_C_COMPILER={C:/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 7.0/arm/bin/iccarm.exe}
-- The C compiler identification is IAR
-- The ASM compiler identification is IAR
-- Found assembler: C:/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 7.0/arm/bin/iasmarm.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 7.0/arm/bin/iccarm.exe
CMake Error at C:/CMake/bin/Modules/Compiler/IAR.cmake:41 (message):
  The IAR compiler for this architecture is not yet supported by CMake.
  Please go to https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues and enter a
  feature request there.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Projects/LabPadIntegration/lpd_firmware/LABPAD_IAR/FIRMWARE/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  C:/Projects/LabPadIntegration/lpd_firmware/LABPAD_IAR/FIRMWARE/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Projects/LabPadIntegration/lpd_firmware/LABPAD_IAR/FIRMWARE/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Projects/LabPadIntegration/lpd_firmware/LABPAD_IAR/FIRMWARE/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

So I get the trace with CMAKE_C_COMPILER which matches well the value I entered, but the MATCH tells it does not match "arm"...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

I've been successfully using CMake to build with the IAR C/C++ Compilers.

The CMake's `find_program()` function worked nicely for finding `CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER` when installed in the usual locations.

As one example, the CMake [toolchain file](https://github.com/IARSystems/cmake-tutorial/blob/abbf75f35691e70fea17f5b1e21f177f6e7cbf90/examples/iar-toolchain.cmake) from [this IAR tutorial](https://github.com/IARSystems/cmake-tutorial) worked for me on both Windows and Linux compilers.

However, it is also possible to set environment variables `CC`, `CXX` and `ASM`. CMake will use such environment variables to set the full path to the compiler. For example:

- On Windows, using the IAR Embedded Workbench:

```
set CC="%PROGRAMFILES%/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 9.1/arm/bin/iccarm.exe"
set CXX="%PROGRAMFILES%/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 9.1/arm/bin/iccarm.exe"
set ASM="%PROGRAMFILES%/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 9.1/arm/bin/iasmarm.exe"
```

- On Linux, using the IAR Build Tools:

```
export CC=/opt/iarsystems/bxarm/arm/bin/iccarm
export CXX=/opt/iarsystems/bxarm/arm/bin/iccarm
export ASM=/opt/iarsystems/bxarm/arm/bin/iasmarm
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got some support from the Cmake issue tracker:
My misunderstanding, this is because the file i give as an arg is not a toolchain file